# Google Material Design - Complex Conditional Filtering Chips in Filter Bar in Data Tables

Tags: datatable, material-design, filtering

I saw a new way of **filtering in data tables in Google Material Design**, but cannot find any guides about the design, nor in the implement process, nor an Angular, React...etc. framework for it.

The GM guide mentioned as ***"filtering chips"*** on https://material.io/components/data-tables/#anatomy ("*Above the header row, a filter bar shows two active filters. Pagination is shown below the last row.*") and linked to the page https://material.io/components/chips/#filter-chips but cannot find and details about the usage of this complex filtering mechanism.

[Screenshot form the Google Material Design - Filtering Chips in Filter bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGIfh.png)

I saw this at work in G-suite's Admin Console where are table views and it works like this:

1. Click in the filter bar
2. A dropdown appears with the filter attributes (name, email...etc.)
3. By clicking to an attribute an input filed shows up where you can put the data
4. By giving the data the chip has been created and other chips can be added

Here are some examples

- [Screenshot: Filter bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNoDY.png)
- [Screenshot: Adding a new filter chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulYIA.png)
- [Screenshot: Adding input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3OF9.png)
- [Screenshot: Adding other filter element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psQdp.png)

I assume you can add any input type like text/number, interval (from-to), checklist...etc.

Is there any library or framework that includes this mechanism because Googling on this topic I couldn't find anything (maybe it's so complex)?

Comment: Did you ever find anything on this topic?  I am running into the same issue - lack of documentation.